# OSError when deploying streamlit web application on Heroku

Tags: python, git, machine-learning, heroku, deployment

I built a web application using streamlit and tried deploying it on heroku. I am getting this error which says

> OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: covid_model.hdf5/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}

The model as well as all the other files are in my github repository and I have enabled automatic deployment in heroku. The webapp works fine on local host.

I tried changing the path of the model, included a "/" in the beginning but the error remains.

This is my [github repo](https://github.com/umarshakeb/insight-covid) where all the code, model and data is posted.

**EDIT:** As advised by James, adding code from the main file that I use to run the webapp:

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('covid_model.hdf5')
def import_and_predict(image_data, model):
    
        size = (160,160)    
        image = ImageOps.fit(image_data, size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
        image = image.convert('RGB')
        image = np.asarray(image)
        image = (image.astype(np.float32) / 255.0)

        img_reshape = image[np.newaxis,...]

        prediction = model.predict(img_reshape)
        
        return prediction

file = st.file_uploader("Please upload an image file", type=["jpg", "png"])
if file is None:
    st.text("You haven't uploaded an image file")
else:
    image = Image.open(file)
    st.image(image, use_column_width=True)
    prediction = import_and_predict(image, model)
    if np.argmax(prediction) == 0:
            st.write("Coronavirus Positive!")
    elif np.argmax(prediction) == 1:
            st.write("Coronavirus Negative!")

    st.text("Probability (0: Corona +, 1: Corona -)")
    st.write(prediction)
```

Comment: Your question should contain the relevant / shortest code to replicate the issue, Otherwise the question is pointless later on because your github won't have the same files anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this error by just moving the below code from this app.py file to the .py file where I wrote the code for building the model **covid_model.hdf5**

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('covid_model.hdf5')

def import_and_predict(image_data, model):
    size = (160,160)    
    image = ImageOps.fit(image_data, size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    image = image.convert('RGB')
    image = np.asarray(image)
    image = (image.astype(np.float32) / 255.0)

    img_reshape = image[np.newaxis,...]

    prediction = model.predict(img_reshape)
    
    return prediction
```